# Regex/Javascript for Matching Values in Parenthesis

Tags: javascript, regex

My web application needs to parse numeric ranges in strings that are enclosed by parenthesis. I've never really understood regex properly so I need some assistance. The code below is kind of what I'm looking to do (I'll then split the string on the hyphen and get the min/max values). Obviously the pattern is wrong - the example below alerts "(10-12) foo (5-10) bar" when my desired result is 1 alert saying (10-12) and the next saying (5-10), or better yet those values without the parenthesis if that's possible.

Any assistance is appreciated.

```
var string = "foo bar (10-12) foo (5-10) bar";
var pattern = /\(.+\)/gi;
matches = string.match(pattern);

for (var i in matches) {
    alert(matches[i]);
}
```

Comment: Start learning regex, it's worth it. Here's a nice cheatsheet http://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make your quantifier lazy by adding a `?` after the `+`. Otherwise, it will greedily consume as much as possible, from your opening `(` to the last `)` in the string.

```
var string = "foo bar (10-12) foo (5-10) bar",
    pattern = /\(.+?\)/g,
    matches = string.match(pattern);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rdwAP/).

If you don't want to include the parenthesis in your matches, generally you'd use a positive lookahead and lookbehind for parenthesis. JavaScript doesn't support lookbehinds (though you can *fake* them). So, use...

```
var string = "foo bar (10-12) foo (5-10) bar",
    pattern = /\((.+?)\)/g,
    match,
    matches = [];

while (match = pattern.exec(string)) {
    matches.push(match[1]);
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zmrYw/).

Also...

- You don't need the `i` flag in your regex; you don't match any letters.
- You should always scope your variables with `var`. In your example, `matches` will be global.
- You shouldn't use a `for (in)` to iterate over an array. You should also check that `match()` doesn't return `null` (if no results were found).

Comment: Excellent - is there a way to remove the parenthesis on the matches too or is that better handled outside of regex?

Comment: @user949738 Certainly, see the part of my answer I'm about to write :)

Comment: @user949738: `string.match(/\(.+?\)/g).join('').match(/\d+\-\d+/g)`

Comment: @KooiInc Interesting. You shouldn't need to escape the `-` in the last regex.

Comment: @alex: you're right. Anyway, if you want to check whilst there are no numeric values between parenthesis in the string to check you can still keep it on one line: `(string.match(pattern)||[]).join('').match(/(\d+-\d+)/g);`

Comment: Thanks for the indepth help guys!

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that your regular expression is *Greedy*, meaning that it will match the first bracket and keep on going till it finds the last bracket. To fix this you have two options, you either add the `?` symbol after the `+` to make it non greedy: `\(.+?\)` or else, match any character except a closing bracket: `\([^)]+\)`.

Both of these regular expressions should do what you need.

Comment: This solution is a better one.